# Unable to install npm latest

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have been trying to install the latest npm with the following command,

```
npm install --save-dev
```

Due to some reason it is failed  and getting the following errors.

```
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> web-automation@git+ssh://git@stash.sprinteins.com:7999/qs/web-test-automation.git
> (node_modules\web-automation): npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> DEPENDENCY: Error while executing: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> DEPENDENCY: C:\Users\momural\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.EXE
> ls-remote -h -t
> ssh://git@stash.sprinteins.com:7999/qs/web-test-automation.gi t npm
> WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm WARN optional SKIPPING
> OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ssh: connect to host stash.sprinteins.com port
> 7999: Connection timed out npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> DEPENDENCY: fatal: Could not read from remote repository. npm WARN
> optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm WARN optional SKIPPING
> OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Please make sure you have the correct access
> rights npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: and the
> repository exists. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm
> WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: exited with error code:
> 128
> 
> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network
> request to https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo failed, reason:
> connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:443 npm ERR! network This is a problem
> related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you
> are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm
> ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm
> ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\momural\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-27T06_54_20_779Z-
```

> Node version is 8.11.2 and npm version is 5.6.0

**Can I know what would be an issue?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm cache verify
```

Then run :

```
npm install --save-dev
```

Comment: No luck. here the results 
[ .................] | fetchMetadata: sill fetchPackageMetaData error for log4js@* request to https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:443

Comment: Check your config settings by running this:  
npm config list  .

You can modify it using this:  
npm config set http-proxy http://proxy_ip:port  ,
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy_ip:port

Answer (score 0):

> ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm

It appears to be network issue. You are not able to download updates. Are you browsing through a proxy?